# 'Expected resource of type xml' error when building signed apk

Tags: android

The error happens on this line:

```
XmlResourceParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.drawable.mySelector);
```

This is reported only when I try to build a signed apk. I don't know how to fix it. If I use `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mySelector)` instead, it reports the error *Incompatible types*

What I'm trying to do is set a color state list for a textview like:

```
XmlResourceParser parser = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mySelector);
ColorStateList colors = ColorStateList.createFromXml(getResources(), parser);
```

If I move the selector xml files from the res/drawables directory to res/xml then they have no effect - the color of the text doesn't change.